# Mostrar todas as datas entre duas datas

Tags: sql

Saudações amigos!
Estou tentando fazer com que a minha query crie várias linhas com os dias correntes através de uma linha onde tenho a data início e fim.

Exemplo:
Data inicio = 01/01/2021,
Data fim = 03/01/2021

Resultado:
01/01/2021
02/01/2021
03/01/2021

Query exemplo:

```
select

    nm_funcionario,
    dt_admissao,
    dt_demissao

from funcionarios
```

Comment: E precisa que isso seja feito no banco de dados mesmo? Não poderia gerar as linhas com a linguagem de programação?

Comment: Infelizmente sim, é uma consulta realizada no banco da aplicação, e não para mostrar em uma aplicação. Preciso inserir em um DW.

Comment: A solução depende do SGBD em questão , pois depende de funções de gerar datas e sequencias artificiais. Os BIs tem artificios também para esta geração de calendários.

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma tabela auxiliar de calendário.

Tabela calendário
Colunas ano, mês, dia, data

Preencha a tabela com todas datas do período que você quer

Une a tabela funcionário com calendário aplicando as regras de filtro que você terá o resultado que quer